# npm doesn't use /node_modules for installation - terminal doesn't find cordova

Tags: macos, node.js, cordova, npm

**Problem**: 
I've installed [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) via `$ sudo nom install -g cordova` (on my mac 10.8.5) but my terminal doesn't find any cordova command.

**More information:**
`type -a npm` returns `npm is /usr/local/bin/npm`
but my `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` directory has no entry 'cordova'.
When I run `npm ls -g` I got nothing back. Just empty spaces.
Strangly cordova has been added to this folder: `/Users/myUser/.npm/cordova`

Anyhow, when I refer the cordova exec of that .npm-folder in my paths I get an error:

```
cordova
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'optimist'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at new CLI (/Users/chris/.npm/cordova/3.1.0-0.2.0/package/src/cli.js:21:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chris/.npm/cordova/3.1.0-0.2.0/package/bin/cordova:41:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I think something with my node-Installation is broken. Does anyone know how I can fix this or where I can find the configuration file of the installation folder on a mac?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running manually

```
$ sudo npm install --global --verbose module_name
```

for every required module.